# Add ' to text in php

Tags: php

I have to add, as you can see below ' in the texts. But if I use the bar, I figure the bar. How is it possible to add the character ' to the string?

I tried with ' but it does not working because \ appears.

```
 <?php
   
   $user_id="name"
   $url_actor="https://domain:8000/".$user_id."/\'".json_decode($response_user->body(), true)[0]["last_name"]."\'";
```

Comment: What result do you expect and could you sort out your question a little, it is not very understandable.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to make it clearer. I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: "But if I use the bar, I figure the bar." - I really don't know how to interpret that

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using double quotes to delineate your string, you do not have to escape the apostrophe: Just use '.

```
print ("There isn't a need to escape the apostrophe.");
print ('... but that\'s not the case in single quotes.');
```

If you use single quotes to mark the beginning and end of the strings, you would need to add the backslash first. (Likewise, inside double quotes, you'd need to escape the ").